# No grid lines inside the panel, but axis ticks present in Gadfly - Julia

Tags: plot, julia, gadfly

So, basically I want to make plot that shows the axis ticks little line but doesn't show the grid lines inside the panel.

I was able to hide the grid lines inside the panel with `Theme(grid_line_width=0mm)` and add a border with `panel_stroke=color("black")`.

It looks like this:

[image]

which is close enough to what I'm looking for except I want little ticks for the axes.

I tried with

```
Guide.xticks(ticks=[0:50:500]),
Guide.yticks(ticks=[0:0.001:0.007])
```

with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt that,s possible. If you look at the help page for themes (http://gadflyjl.org/themes.html), there is nothing for ticks. Maybe opening an issue would help: https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/issues

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments there is no property to set the ticks as required.